# How to set valid username and password in login activity template android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

The problem is when i login with login activity template I can use random username and password so I want to add a valid username and password for login

**LOGIN FORM STATE**

```
class LoginFormState {
@Nullable
private Integer usernameError;
@Nullable
private Integer passwordError;
private boolean isDataValid;

LoginFormState(@Nullable Integer usernameError, @Nullable Integer passwordError) {
    this.usernameError = usernameError;
    this.passwordError = passwordError;
    this.isDataValid = false;
}

LoginFormState(boolean isDataValid) {
    this.usernameError = null;
    this.passwordError = null;
    this.isDataValid = isDataValid;
}

@Nullable
Integer getUsernameError() {
    return usernameError;
}

@Nullable
Integer getPasswordError() {
    return passwordError;
}

boolean isDataValid() {

    return isDataValid;
}
```

}

Comment: To make sure someone can actually point you in the right direction you would have to provide some examples and maybe tell / show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

First you have to define two TextView asking username and password of the user. The password TextView must have inputType set to password. Its syntax is given below −

```
<EditText
   android:id = "@+id/editText2"
   android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
   android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
   android:inputType = "textPassword" />

<EditText
   android:id = "@+id/editText1"
   android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
   android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
/>
```

Define a button with login text and set its onClick Property. After that define the function mentioned in the onClick property in the java file

```
<Button
   android:id = "@+id/button1"
   android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
   android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
   android:onClick = "login"
   android:text = "@string/Login" 
/>
```

In the java file, inside the method of onClick get the username and passwords text using getText() and toString() method and match it with the text using equals() function.

```
EditText username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
EditText password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);     

public void login(View view){
   if(username.getText().toString().equals("admin") && password.getText().toString().equals("admin")){

   //correcct password
   }else{
   //wrong password
}
```

The last thing you need to do is to provide a security mechanism, so that unwanted attempts should be avoided. For this initialize a variable and on each false attempt, decrement it. And when it reaches to 0, disable the login button.

```
    enter code here

int counter = 3;
counter--;

if(counter==0){
   //disble the button, close the application e.t.c
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 String user_name = edt_username.getText().toString();
                 String user_pass = edt_userpass.getText().toString();

    if(user_name.equals("test") && user_pass.equals("test")){

       // now login successfully
    }
    else{
       // failed to login
    }
            }
        });
```